# Bean Context in Spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

The application works perfectly with the following config files:

My Web.XML is as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/classes/spring/spring-context.xml,
      /WEB-INF/classes/spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<context:component-scan base-package="biz.canisrigel.slapMe" />

<!-- enable autowire -->
<context:annotation-config />
```

My spring-context.xml is

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="biz.canisrigel.slapMe" />

<!-- enable autowire -->
<context:annotation-config />


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/slapMe" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="adminadmin" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="biz.canisrigel.slapMe.bean" />
</bean>

<!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="biz.canisrigel.slapMe.mapper" />
</bean>
```

I couldn't run spring security properly cause earlier spring-context.xml was the xml config file for dispatcher servlet for MVC. So I moved spring-context to contextConfigLocation. But then I had to provide something to dispatcher servlet.

My problem is that mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and spring-context is having same data. If I remove mvc-dispatcher its an error. If I don't place the contents of mvc-dispatcher in spring context then also error occurs.

Where am I going wrong in my understanding of concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Your `web.xml` looks correct
- The `InternalResourceViewResolver` should only exist in your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` since it is directly related to MVC -- remove it from your `spring-context.xml`
- You can have `context:component-scan` in both configuration files, but they should be scanning different packages.  The one in your servlet xml will generally be component scanning your controller packages (and anything else directly related to MVC), and the one in your parent spring context xml will generally be scanning your services, DAOs, etc.  In general, your component scan packages should be very specific; **you should never point it towards the base package of your entire application!**
- You can remove `context:annotation-config` -- it is redundant if you have `context:component-scan`

Comment: thanks. just a doubt you said i should never point component scan to base package. but i have something like biz.canisrigel.slapMe.dao and biz.canisrigel.slapMe.bo biz.canisrigel.slapMe.controllers. so i have to use biz.canisrigel.slapMe for scanning

Comment: You should have a separate `context:component-scan` for each of those packages, then...

Answer (score 0):

Your MVC context should have only configuration related to MVC which generally includes ViewResolvers, FileUpload, PropertyFiles, Message/Theme Resolvers etc. Your applicationContext will have beans related to DAO, Service and other utils. The security file should have security configuration. To understand better and to know good/recommended practices, check out the [spring greehouse](https://github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse) code.